# Using Euler Eqns to separate a quadratic into real and imaginary components

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, delay-differential-equations

I'm working on a research paper on [Delay Differential Equations](https://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/s4/f2/dsk1/tape9/PQDD_0016/MQ49407.pdf) and have arrived at the same characteristic equation for the linearised system:

\begin{align} 
\lambda^2+p\lambda+r+(s\lambda+q)e^{-\lambda\tau}=0
\end{align}

Defining $\tau\neq0$, we can use $\lambda=i\omega$, where $\omega\in\Re$, as a root of this characteristic equation.

Substituting this into the characteristic equation, I have:

\begin{align}
0&=i^2\omega^2+pi\omega+r+(si\omega+q)e^{-i\omega\tau} \\
&=-\omega^2+qe^{-i\omega\tau}+pi\omega+r+is\omega e^{-\omega\tau}
\end{align}

Using the Euler equations, I rewrote $e^{\pm i\omega\tau}$ as

\begin{align}
e^{i\omega\tau}&=\cos(\omega\tau)+i\sin(\omega\tau) \\
e^{-i\omega\tau}&=\cos(\omega\tau)-i\sin(\omega\tau).
\end{align}

This gives me
\begin{align}
0&=-\omega^2+q\left(\cos(\omega\tau)-i\sin(\omega\tau)\right)+pi\omega+r+is\omega(\cos(\omega\tau)-i\sin(\omega\tau)) \\
&=-\omega^2+q\cos(\omega\tau)-qi\sin(\omega\tau)+i\omega p+r +is\omega\cos(\omega\tau)-i^2s\omega\sin(\omega\tau) \\
&=-\omega^2+q\cos(\omega\tau)-qi\sin(\omega\tau)+i\omega p+r +is\omega\cos(\omega\tau)+s\omega\sin(\omega\tau)
\end{align}

I'm then confused about how they have evaluated 
\begin{align}
F(i\omega)&= r-\omega^2-s\omega\sin(\omega\tau)+q\cos(\omega\tau)=0 \hspace{5mm} (5.8)\\
G(i\omega)&= p\omega + s\omega\cos(\omega\tau)+q\sin(\omega\tau)=0 \hspace{12mm} (5.9)
\end{align}

I've tried taking out the real and imaginary components of this equation:
\begin{align}
F(i\omega)&= r-\omega^2+s\omega\sin(\omega\tau)+q\cos(\omega\tau)=0 \\
G(i\omega)&= p\omega + s\omega\cos(\omega\tau)-q\sin(\omega\tau)=0
\end{align}

If anyone can explain what the step I'm missing is? What have I done wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I checked both, it seems you're right. It remains to hope that the subsequent results in the paper are nevertheless correct. [please write in your question "(5.8) and (5.9)"]

Comment: How are $F$ and $G$ defined ? Besides, a little advice : I have learned not to trust blindly M. Sc. theses (I wouldn't say the same thing for Ph. D. theses)...